# How to access the state of a components style?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I am trying to create a quiz and if the user presses the right button, its background turns green and otherwise, it turns red. Question component has five attributes (four question choices and one answer), myfunction compares the answer and the choice and if they are equal, I want the background of this option to turn green, and red otherwise but I am not sure how to do it.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ImageBackground
} from "react-native";

class Question extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myfunction = this.myfunction.bind(this);
  }

  state = {
    // possible backgrounds of choices. default is grey.
    grey: "rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.3)",
    red: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)",
    green: "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)"
  };

  myfunction(f1, f2) {
    if (f1 == f2) {
      console.warn("Right choice"); //to test it

    } else {
      console.warn("Wrong choice");
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: 280, width: 360, flex: 1 }}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: "row"
          }}
        >
          <TouchableOpacity // first option A
            name="a"
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              backgroundColor: this.state.notral,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center"
            }}
            onPress={() =>
              this.myfunction(
                this.props.answer,
                this.props.f0,
                this.children.backgroundColor
              )
            }
          >
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 23, textAlign: "center", color: "white" }}>
              {this.props.f0}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>

          <TouchableOpacity // second option B
            name="b"
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              backgroundColor: this.state.notral,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center"
            }}
            onPress={() => this.myfunction(this.props.answer, this.props.f1)}
          >
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 23, textAlign: "center", color: "white" }}>
              {this.props.f1}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            name="c"
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              backgroundColor: this.state.notral,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center"
            }}
            onPress={() => this.myfunction(this.props.answer, this.props.f2)}
          >
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 23, textAlign: "center", color: "white" }}>
              {this.props.f2}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            name="d"
            style={{
              flex: 1,
              backgroundColor: this.state.notral,
              justifyContent: "center",
              alignItems: "center"
            }}
            onPress={() => this.myfunction(this.props.answer, this.props.f3)}
          >
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 23, textAlign: "center", color: "white" }}>
              {this.props.f3}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text
              style={{
                fontSize: 30,
                textAlign: "center",
                marginTop: 35,
                marginBottom: 25
              }}
              onPress={this.myfunction}
            >
              Which one is the right answer?
            </Text>

            <ImageBackground
              style={{ height: 280, width: 360, flex: 1 }}
              source={require("./assets/wol.jpg")} // wolf of wall street scene. question itself is this image.
            >
              <Question 
                style={{ height: 280, width: 360, flex: 1 }}
                f0="Gone Girl"
                f1="Wolf of Wall Street"
                f2="Us"
                f3="Skin That I Live In"
                answer="Wolf of Wall Street"
              />
            </ImageBackground>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one simple way is to make a variable for each button color state. then on your function when clicking, you can change that to another color

```
class Question extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.myfunction = this.myfunction.bind(this);
    }

    state = {
        f0color: "rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.3)",
        f1color: "rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.3)",
        f2color: "rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.3)",
        f3color: "rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.3)",
        // possible backgrounds of choices. default is grey.
        grey: "rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.3)",
        red: "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)",
        green: "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)"
    };

    myfunction(f1, f2, colorState) {
        if (f1 == f2) {
            this.setState({
                [colorState] : "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.3)"
            })
            this.state[colorState]
            console.warn("Right choice"); //to test it

        } else {
            this.setState({
                [colorState] : "rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.3)"
            })
            this.state[colorState]
            console.warn("Wrong choice");
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <View style={{ height: 280, width: 360, flex: 1 }}>
            <View
            style={{
                flex: 1,
                flexDirection: "row"
            }}
            >
            <TouchableOpacity // first option A
                name="a"
                style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: this.state.f0color,
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center"
                }}
                onPress={() =>
                this.myfunction(
                    this.props.answer,
                    this.props.f0,
                    'f0color'
                )
                }
            >
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 23, textAlign: "center", color: "white" }}>
                {this.props.f0}
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity // second option B
                name="b"
                style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor:  this.state.f1color,
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center"
                }}
                onPress={() => this.myfunction(this.props.answer, this.props.f1, 'f1color')}
            >
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 23, textAlign: "center", color: "white" }}>
                {this.props.f1}
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <TouchableOpacity
                name="c"
                style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: this.state.f2color,
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center"
                }}
                onPress={() => this.myfunction(this.props.answer, this.props.f2, 'f2color')}
            >
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 23, textAlign: "center", color: "white" }}>
                {this.props.f2}
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
                name="d"
                style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: this.state.f3color,
                justifyContent: "center",
                alignItems: "center"
                }}
                onPress={() => this.myfunction(this.props.answer, this.props.f3, 'f3color')}
            >
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 23, textAlign: "center", color: "white" }}>
                {this.props.f3}
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
        );
    }
    }

    export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Text
                style={{
                    fontSize: 30,
                    textAlign: "center",
                    marginTop: 35,
                    marginBottom: 25
                }}
                onPress={this.myfunction}
                >
                Which one is the right answer?
                </Text>

                <ImageBackground
                style={{ height: 280, width: 360, flex: 1 }}
                source={require("./assets/wol.jpg")} // wolf of wall street scene. question itself is this image.
                >
                <Question 
                    style={{ height: 280, width: 360, flex: 1 }}
                    f0="Gone Girl"
                    f1="Wolf of Wall Street"
                    f2="Us"
                    f3="Skin That I Live In"
                    answer="Wolf of Wall Street"
                />
                </ImageBackground>
            </View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
        );
    }
    }
```